# Spark DataTables: where is partitionBy?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

A common Spark processing flow we have is something like this:

Loading:

```
rdd = sqlContext.parquetFile("mydata/")
rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: (row.id,(some stuff)))
rdd = rdd.filter(....)
rdd = rdd.partitionBy(rdd.getNumPatitions())
```

Processing by `id` (**this is why we do the `partitionBy` above**!)

```
rdd.reduceByKey(....)
rdd.join(...)
```

However, Spark 1.3 changed `sqlContext.parquetFile` to return `DataFrame` instead of `RDD`, and it no longer has the `partitionBy`, `getNumPartitions`, and `reduceByKey` methods.

**What do we do now with `partitionBy`?**

We can replace the loading code with something like

```
rdd = sqlContext.parquetFile("mydata/").rdd
rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: (row.id,(some stuff)))
rdd = rdd.filter(....)
rdd = rdd.partitionBy(rdd.getNumPatitions())
df = rdd.map(lambda ...: Row(...)).toDF(???)
```

and use `groupBy` instead of `reduceByKey`.

Is this the right way?

PS. Yes, I understand that `partitionBy` is *not* necessary for `groupBy` et al. However, without a prior `partitionBy`, *each* `join`, `groupBy` &c may have to do cross-node operations. I am looking for a way to **guarantee** that all operations requiring grouping by my key will run **local**.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that, since version **1.6**, [`repartition(self, numPartitions, *cols)`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L426-L484) does what I need:

```
.. versionchanged:: 1.6
```

> Added optional arguments to specify the partitioning columns. 
>   Also made `numPartitions` optional if partitioning columns are specified.

Answer (score 0):

Since `DataFrame` provide us an abstraction of **Table** and **Column** over `RDD`, the most convenient way to manipulate `DataFrame` is to use these abstraction along with the specific *table manipulations methods* that DataFrame enables us.

On a DataFrame, we could:

- transform the table schema with `select()` \ `udf()` \ `as()`
- filter rows out by `filter()` or `where()`
- fire an aggregation through `groupBy()` and `agg()`
- or other analytic job using `sample()` \ `join()` \ `union()`
- persist your result using `saveAsTable()` \ `saveAsParquet()` \ `insertIntoJDBC()`

Please refer to [Spark SQL and DataFrame Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) for more details.

Therefore, a common job looks like:

```scala
val people = sqlContext.parquetFile("...")
val department = sqlContext.parquetFile("...")

people.filter("age > 30")
  .join(department, people("deptId") === department("id"))
  .groupBy(department("name"), "gender")
  .agg(avg(people("salary")), max(people("age")))
```

And for your specific requirements, this could look like:

```scala
val t = sqlContext.parquetFile()
t.filter().select().groupBy().agg()
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the most important question was: how do I do `partitionBy`?

Comment: @sds, id is a column name ?

Comment: @sds, so you mean to shuffle data according to a key then reduce by key later?

Comment: yes, I want to partition by the key and then do _many_ things on it later: aggregate, join &c &c

Comment: @sds, you can simply accomplish this by `groupBy('id')`, spark sql would translate this into repartition(_your partitionBy_) procedure

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L736-758, see the comment please

Comment: So you want to pre shuffle the dataset once, and reuse it repeatedly

Comment: Great, so how do I pre shuffle?